# is there a way to resize background images FROM html

Tags: html, image, gif, giphy

so, a normal way to get the background in html is this:

```
<style>

body {
  background-image: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/itTRilS6MUfqMCQbgZ/giphy.gif');
}

</style>
```

but now let's suppose i need the background to be BIGGER, so much big that GIPHY just won't allow, you can't use `width=''` and `height=''`, so now is there a way i can just do i straight from the html?

Comment: or, even more helpful, can you fit it to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `background-size` and `background-position` in CSS to play with.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position